# Creating Nested Lists from Arrays - Codeigniter, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ok long time coder, first time stuck ( I think due to not seeing the woods through the trees!)

any how I have data being returned in an array. 
When foreached out one of the data fields is the part number.

As an example the data set looks like this (I've removed some as it repeats)

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1628
        [partnum] => 02030200104bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS400 4 BLACK D RING CHUKKA PAD COLLAR PUDD SOLE STEEL TOEandMID S1P STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1717-1727
        [location] => 
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1629
        [partnum] => 02030200105bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS400 5 BLACK D RING CHUKKA PAD COLLAR PUDD SOLE STEEL TOEandMID S1P STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1717-1727
        [location] => 
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1630
        [partnum] => 02030200106bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS400 6 BLACK D RING CHUKKA PAD COLLAR PUDD SOLE STEEL TOEandMID S1P STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1717-1727
        [location] => 
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )


[11] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1638
        [partnum] => 02030200205bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS609 5 BLACK PAD COLLAR/TONGUE PU DD SOLE STEEL TOECAP and MIDSOLE S3 STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1728-1735
        [location] => C36
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
        [ass_prod] => 
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1639
        [partnum] => 02030200206bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS609 6 BLACK PAD COLLAR/TONGUE PU DD SOLE STEEL TOECAP and MIDSOLE S3 STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1728-1735
        [location] => C36
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1640
        [partnum] => 02030200207bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS609 7 BLACK PAD COLLAR/TONGUE PU DD SOLE STEEL TOECAP and MIDSOLE S3 STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1728-1735
        [location] => C36
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1641
        [partnum] => 02030200208bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS609 8 BLACK PAD COLLAR/TONGUE PU DD SOLE STEEL TOECAP and MIDSOLE S3 STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1728-1735
        [location] => C36
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1640
        [partnum] => 02030200207bla
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS609 7 BLACK PAD COLLAR/TONGUE PU DD SOLE STEEL TOECAP and MIDSOLE S3 STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1728-1735
        [location] => C36
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1642
        [partnum] => 02030200108yel
        [cat] => PPE
        [class] => FOOT PROTECTION
        [subcat] => BOOTS
        [name] => BOOT SS400 8 YELLOW D RING CHUKKA PAD COLLAR PUDD SOLE STEEL TOEandMID S1P STES
        [is_over] => 0
        [price] => 1
        [image] => 1728-1735
        [location] => C36
        [purchase] => 1
        [hire] => 0
        [hide] => 0
        [hasother] => 0
        [name_soundex] => 
        [options] => 
        [ass_prod] => 
    )
```

)

The first 9 characters are the product code so i do

```
$thisval = substr($t['partnum'], 0, 9);
```

and the next 2 characters are the size

```
$thissize = substr($t['partnum'], 9, 2);
```

and the last 3 characters are the colour

```
$thissize = substr($t['partnum'], 11, 3);
```

All i need to do is
if the first 9 characters match, create a select for each of the last 2 characters where the first nine match, so they all appear in the dropdown as a selectable size
and it takes the last 3 characters and makes them selectable colours

If a new 9 characters comes along, it takes that and starts a new one . . . ?

So you would end up like you would on a store with an item and a colour and a size selector

From the above data
I'd be looking for 2 items, one with a size selector and a colour selector with black and yellow
and one with a size selector and a colour selector of just black.

Any help would be great!

I'm thinking it should work like

```
If(is_array($products)){
$check="";
foreach($products as $key => $p){
$substring1 = substr($p['partnum'], 9,2);
$nexttwo = substr($p['partnum'],9,2);
If($check == $substring1){

}else{
If(is_array($products){
Foreach($products as $key => $t){
$substring2 = substr($t['partnum'], 9,2);
$nexttwo2 = substr($t['partnum'],9,2);
If($substring1 != $substring2){
Echo "<li>" . $p['itemname'] . "<ul>";
}else{
If($substring1 == $substring2){
Echo "<li>". $nexttwo2."</li>;
}else{
Echo "</ul>";
}
}
</li>
$check = $substring1;
}
}
}
```

Comment: All kinds, but I'm not getting anything sticking.

I have a series of foreach loops and if and checks to group together the items, categories and sub-categories, just when i now get to the items, its not working... I'm thinking do i need to split my array data up?

Comment: if i do 

    echo $thisval . " Size=" . $thissize . br();
 i get

020302001 Size=03
020302001 Size=04
020302001 Size=05
020302001 Size=06
020302001 Size=07
020302001 Size=08
020302001 Size=09

Now i just need  to get them grouped

Comment: What you desire is a really long(and tedious) work. Putting up a segment of code you tried helps our thinking.

Comment: I'll post what I've done shortly when I go back to my computer. Just if loops with comparisons and if a variable matches the current variable then group it

Comment: Updated with what I think should happen just to group them together for now. Once grouped I can change them to select options

Comment: Why don't you do this with SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$check = '';
$colouris = "";
$sizeis = "";
$first = true;
if(is_array($products)){ 
foreach($products as $key => $p){
    $substring1 = substr($p['partnum'], 0,9);
    $sizeis = substr($p['partnum'],9,4);
    $colouris = substr($p['partnum'],13,2);
if ($substring1 != $check) {

        if (!$first) {
            echo '</select></label>';
        }
        echo '<label>' . $substring1 . '<select>';

        $check = $substring1;
    }
    if(!$sizeis){
        echo '<option>No Options</option>';
    }
    else{


        echo '<option>' . $sizeof . " " . $colourof  .'</option>';
        $first = false;
        $colouris = "";
        $sizeis = "";
    }


 }
}
```

The size of and colour of variables are set from some simple if,elses on the substr

```
if($sizeis === "28SH"){
        $sizeof = "28 Short";
    }
    elseif($sizeis === "30SH"){
        $sizeof = "30 Short";
    }
if($colouris == "YE"){
        $colourof = "Yellow";
    }
    elseif($colouris == "OR"){
        $colourof = "Orange";
    }
```

e.t.c. e.t.c.

This gets me instead of 24 items on a page, I'll have 4 items with 6 options in a drop down.
The select options would be

```
Medium Blue
Medium Yellow
Medium Green
2XL Orange
2XL Yellow
2XL Green
```

I'd like to flesh the select builder up, to build 2 selects, but I have it all in one for now